# Login control - Controls do not exist in current context

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Trying to set up the Login control as a User control, but none of the controls exist in the current context? I also tried adding to a master page with the same error showing up.

None of my code below is recognised? What's going on here please? I've rebuilt the solution many times.

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(this.UserName.Text, this.Password.Text))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, RememberMe.Checked);
    }
    else
    {
         Msg.Text = "Login failed. Please check your user name and password and try again.";
    }
```

Comment: When you say that your code is not recognized could you be more specific? Not recognized by whom? For what motive or at least what motive is presented to you (you know like a compile error message or something)?

Comment: Here are two of the compile errors:
The name Membership does not exist in the current context
The name FormsAuthentication does not exist in the current context.
...and so on for the textbox controls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have [used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) the proper namespaces and the `System.Web` assembly is referenced in your project:

- [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) - defined in `System.Web.Security` namespace in the `System.Web` assembly
- [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) - defined in `System.Web.Security` namespace in the `System.Web` assembly

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Maing progress here, I had forgotten to add the System.Web.Security namespace, so FormsAuthentication and Mambership are now recognised. However the textbox controls are not being recognised. The error message is "login does not contain a definition for UserName and no extension method UserName"